# How can I decide which declarative model to instantiate, based on row information

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm building a webapp that has optional Facebook Login. The users created through the Facebook API are handled differently at several points in my application. I want to encapsulate these differences in a subclass of `Person` that overrides methods.

```
class Person(Model):
    def get_profile_picture(self):
        return profile_pictures.url(self.picture)

class FacebookPerson(Person):
    def get_profile_picture(self):
        return 'http:/.../%s.jpg' % self.graph_id
```

I would like to avoid the nasty `if self.graph_id` and just query the Person model and get the right object for each user.

I've thought of hacking the metaclass to add the FacebookPerson as a base. Obviously I would like to avoid such voodoo.

I'm using Flask and Flask-SQLAlchemy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general idea would be to store the model's class name as metadata in each row, and when you instantiate the object, do something like:

```
def query(self):
    # stuff
    return model_class(data)
```

To do this in SQLAlchemy, you might look at making Person the base class to something like BasicPerson and FacebookPerson, and in Person.**init**(), use the metadata to initialize to the proper subclass.

For example, the idea would be than when this query returns, user will have been initialized to the proper subclass:

```
user = session.query(Person).filter_by(name='james').first()
```

You will probably need to modify this concept a bit for SQLAlchemy (I haven't used it in a while), but that's the general idea.

Or, you could do something like store the metadata in a cookie with the user_id, and then when they log in again, use the metadata to pass the proper class to the user query:

```
user = session.query(FacebookPerson).filter_by(name='james').first()
```

If you want this to be generic so that the metatdata is meaningful to non-Python clients, instead of storing the model's class name, store the model's "object_type" and have something in each client library that maps object_types to classes.